Keeping diverging branches in sync with each other
I have two branches A and B which have diverged.
I want to periodically synchronize them with each other (commit most changes from B to A, and commit most changes from A to B).
When merging in either direction, this might involve rejecting entire files, or just portions of a file.
First thing I did was:
git checkout A
git merge --squash B

I don't care about the commit history of B, and in fact I specifically don't even want it.
I just want a commit that says "bring over changes from B".
I resolved all the changes and committed it to A. Then I did the reverse:
git checkout B
git merge --squash A

At this point, git only recognizes a couple of files have changed.    Specifically, if I run git diff --name-only A I get a massive list of differences, on the order of 100 different files.
But git merge A only wants to merge changes in about 5 of those files, and the other are completely ignored.
How do I make git attempt to merge any files which differ between the two branches?

Everything as expected.

Here is a demo to show you how it work (as you already know :-))
At the end of the script you will see how "git" squash the commits and "fix" the different files as you described them

#!/bin/bash

###
### Merge conflict demo
###

# Create a new demo repository
rm -rf   /tmp/tempRepository
echo -e ""
echo -e "* Preparation(s)"
echo -e ""

mkdir -p /tmp/tempRepository
git init /tmp/tempRepository
cd       /tmp/tempRepository

echo -e "------------------------------------------------------------------------"
echo -e "$ git checkout -b branchA"
echo -e ""

# Create a new branch
git checkout -b branchA

# Add some content to it
echo -e "------------------------------------------------------------------------"
echo -e "* Initial commit to branchA"
echo -e ""
echo  "Hello World" > hello.txt
git   add hello.txt
git   commit -m "Initial commit"

# Create a new branch from branchA
echo -e "-------------------------------------------------------------------------"
echo -e "* Create branch B branchA (and dont switch to branchB)"
echo -e ""
echo -e "$ git checkout -b branchB"
echo -e ""
echo -e "git branch branchB"
git branch branchB

# Add some content to it (and generate conflict)
echo -e "-------------------------------------------------------------------------"
echo -e "* Create change in branchA (after branchB was created from A)"
echo -e ""
echo  "Hello World2" > hello.txt
git   add hello.txt
git   commit -m "Commit on branchA"

# Add some ramdom commits to branchA
echo -e "-------------------------------------------------------------------------"
echo -e "* Add random content to branchA"
echo -e ""
for i in {1..5};
do
    echo  "$RANDOM" > A-$RANDOM.txt
    git   add .
    git   commit -m "Commit [$i] on branchA"
done

# Add some ramdom commits to branchB
echo -e "-------------------------------------------------------------------------"
echo -e "* Checkout & Add random content to branchB"
echo -e ""

git checkout branchB
for i in {1..5};
do
    echo  "$RANDOM" > B-$RANDOM.txt
    git   add .
    git   commit -m "Commit [$i] on branchB"
done

# Checkout branchA
echo -e "-------------------------------------------------------------------------"
echo -e "$ git checkout branchA"
echo -e ""
git checkout branchA

# Merge branchB into branchA with squash
echo -e "-------------------------------------------------------------------------"
echo -e "$ git merge --squash branchB"
echo -e ""
git merge --squash branchB

# See the diffrence
echo -e "-------------------------------------------------------------------------"
echo -e "$ git diff --name-only branchA"
echo -e ""
git diff --name-only branchA

# Wait for user input
echo "Press any key to continue..."
read -n 1

# Check the staging area
echo -e "-------------------------------------------------------------------------"
echo -e ""
echo -e "$ git status"
echo -e ""
git status

# Commit the changes
echo -e "-------------------------------------------------------------------------"
echo -e ""
echo -e "* Commit the changes (results of the squashing)"
echo -e ""
echo -e "$ git commit -m"Cool commit""
echo -e ""
git commit -m"Cool commit"

# View the list of chanegs files
echo -e "-------------------------------------------------------------------------"
echo -e ""
echo -e "* Verify that all is "fixed""
echo -e ""
echo -e "$ git whatchanged --oneline  | cat"
echo -e ""
git whatchanged --oneline  | cat

Output

* Preparation(s)

Initialized empty Git repository in /private/tmp/tempRepository/.git/
------------------------------------------------------------------------
$ git checkout -b branchA

------------------------------------------------------------------------
* Initial commit to branchA

[branchA (root-commit) 5582b4e] Initial commit
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 hello.txt
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
* Create branch B branchA (and dont switch to branchB)

$ git checkout -b branchB

git branch branchB
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
* Create change in branchA (after branchB was created from A)

[branchA ad5738d] Commit on branchA
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
* Add random content to branchA

[branchA d20f973] Commit [1] on branchA
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 A-8451.txt
[branchA 3690e93] Commit [2] on branchA
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 A-18701.txt
[branchA c90a2fa] Commit [3] on branchA
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 A-19933.txt
[branchA ab06b25] Commit [4] on branchA
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 A-8861.txt
[branchA 2261f61] Commit [5] on branchA
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 A-25228.txt
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
* Checkout & Add random content to branchB

[branchB ff49491] Commit [1] on branchB
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 B-30774.txt
[branchB 4e96ed8] Commit [2] on branchB
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 B-30658.txt
[branchB 299fd31] Commit [3] on branchB
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 B-28765.txt
[branchB 2bc2c61] Commit [4] on branchB
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 B-4777.txt
[branchB 7321b52] Commit [5] on branchB
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 B-6593.txt
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
$ git checkout branchA

-------------------------------------------------------------------------
$ git merge --squash branchB

Squash commit -- not updating HEAD
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
$ git diff --name-only branchA

B-28765.txt
B-30658.txt
B-30774.txt
B-4777.txt
B-6593.txt
Press any key to continue...
-------------------------------------------------------------------------

$ git status

On branch branchA
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
    new file:   B-28765.txt
    new file:   B-30658.txt
    new file:   B-30774.txt
    new file:   B-4777.txt
    new file:   B-6593.txt

-------------------------------------------------------------------------

* Commit the changes (results of the squashing)

$ git commit -mCool commit

[branchA 216cca4] Cool commit
 5 files changed, 5 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 B-28765.txt
 create mode 100644 B-30658.txt
 create mode 100644 B-30774.txt
 create mode 100644 B-4777.txt
 create mode 100644 B-6593.txt
-------------------------------------------------------------------------

* Verify that all is fixed

$ git whatchanged --oneline  | cat

216cca4 Cool commit
:000000 100644 0000000 62eb110 A    B-28765.txt
:000000 100644 0000000 c6d2238 A    B-30658.txt
:000000 100644 0000000 0694fb8 A    B-30774.txt
:000000 100644 0000000 87768b1 A    B-4777.txt
:000000 100644 0000000 179d206 A    B-6593.txt
2261f61 Commit [5] on branchA
:000000 100644 0000000 76fdbb7 A    A-25228.txt
ab06b25 Commit [4] on branchA
:000000 100644 0000000 d5edada A    A-8861.txt
c90a2fa Commit [3] on branchA
:000000 100644 0000000 d69a04c A    A-19933.txt
3690e93 Commit [2] on branchA
:000000 100644 0000000 e9880db A    A-18701.txt
d20f973 Commit [1] on branchA
:000000 100644 0000000 79e927c A    A-8451.txt
ad5738d Commit on branchA
:100644 100644 557db03 b2b6f00 M    hello.txt
5582b4e Initial commit
:000000 100644 0000000 557db03 A    hello.txt


So what command do i run to have it automatically attempt to merge all different files?  Do i need to manually git checkout A — file manually for every single one and look at each ones diff to manually resolve conflicts?

If there are conflicts they will appear automatically, just fix them if you have any

I think my problem is not clearly explained in the OP so i will edit to add a concrete reproducible example

I spended a lot of time writing the example for you based upon your question :-(

I experimented with this some more and came to the conclusion that your answer does actually correctly answer my question, and I didn't understand, so thank you.


I don't care about the commit history of B, and in fact I specifically don't even want it. I just want a commit that says "bring over changes from B".

Then you might want to merge B into A with the ours merge strategy*. This strategy doesn't actually bring any of the changes from the other branch (B) into the target branch (A). It just flags the changes as merged and maintains only the version of the target branch.

This should not be confused with the ours merge strategy, which does not even look at what the other tree contains at all. It discards everything the other tree did, declaring our history contains all that happened in it.

git merge -s ours B

* When reading the documentation don't get confused by the first paragraph (the one that I haven't attached), that section refers to the -X option, which is the logic that Git falls back to only in case of conflicts. The second paragraph instead refers to the -s option, which maintains only the version of the target branch and ignores the other branch whether there are conflicts or not.
